# How to save SVG file with Inkscape CLI?

Tags: command-line, svg, inkscape

I'm working with Inkscape in cli no (`--without-gui` or `-z`) to :

1. Select multiple nodes by id (`hanzi`, `pinyin`) ;
2. Create an union of them ;
3. Save as a new file (`test-union-cli.svg`).

### Command

So I use this command:

```
inkscape -z -f ./䖠-x45A0.svg \
    --select=hanzi --select=pinyin \
    --verb SelectionUnion --verb FileSaveCopyAs \
    --verb=FileClose test-union-cli.svg
```

### Output error

> ** (inkscape:27462): CRITICAL **: Inkscape::XML::Document* sp_repr_read_file(const gchar*, const gchar*): assertion
>   `Inkscape::IO::file_test( filename, G_FILE_TEST_EXISTS )' failed
>
> ** (inkscape:27462): CRITICAL **: Inkscape::XML::Document* sp_repr_read_file(const gchar*, const gchar*): assertion
>   `Inkscape::IO::file_test( filename, G_FILE_TEST_EXISTS )' failed
>
> ** (inkscape:27462): WARNING **: Specified document test-union-cli.svg cannot be opened (does not exist or not a valid SVG file)

The file `test-union-cli.svg` is not supposed to exists. So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### tl;dr

1. You can't save to a different file than the one open. So edit a copy ;
2. Verb **need the GUI**, don't use `-z` or `--without-gui`.

### Verbs don't take parameters

Asked on `#inkscape` and it come out that currently (`Inkscape 0.48.3.1 r9886 (Jan 29 2013)`) doesn't support verb's parameters:

> verbs do not take arguments -> you cannot save a file you opened with
>   '-f' under a different name copy the file first (e.g. in the script),
>   and edit and save the copied file

There is a *bug confirmed* on this topic (see: [Bug:Provide scriptable method of saving files](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/361237)).

### Verb imply GUI

> verbs currently (with stable) always require to open the GUI (even if
>   no interaction is required)

Bug is confirmed [Allow suppressing the GUI (-z) when using --verb option(s)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/843260) and added to whishlist.

### Temporary Solution

Newer version of Inkscape may fix this "issue", currently you can solve it by doing

```
cp 䖠-x45A0.svg test-union-cli.svg && inkscape -g -f ./test-union-cli.svg \
    --select=hanzi --select=pinyin --verb=SelectionUnion \
    --verb=FileSave --verb=FileClose
```

## Hope (v.049)

Improvement is on its way [lp:~7-eric/inkscape/effectscript](https://code.launchpad.net/~7-eric/inkscape/effectscript):

> read the commit log of revision 12388 here
>   https://code.launchpad.net/~7-eric/inkscape/effectscript - this was
>   merged into trunk recently, and AFAIU allows to run boolops verbs via
>   cli without GUI
>   -> likely the next major version of inkscape (0.49) will have better cli support

Comment: Using 0.91 still not working. Using --verb and -z brings inkscape to segfault. https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/843260